# Extract keywords from a column in CSV and save to another column

Tags: python, pandas, text

I had a bunch of text files of news broadcasts which I saved into a CSV in this format:

```
id   text
001  Ad sales boost Time Warner profit\n\nQuarterly...
002  Dollar gains on Greenspan speech\n\nThe dollar...
003  Yukos unit buyer faces loan claim\n\nThe owner...
004  High fuel prices hit BA's profits\n\nBritish A...
005  Pernod takeover talk lifts Domecq\n\nShares in...
```

and the list continues...

I want to iterate through the `text` column and find if it contains specific keywords from a list of keywords ..say, `['sales','gains', 'loan', 'forex']` and if they exist, save them in the next column as a dictionary.
`{key: value}` where key=items from list and value= number of the times those items have occurred in that row.

OUTPUT:

```
id   text                                                       occurrences 
001  Ad sales boost Time Warner profit\n\nQuarterly...           {'sales':1}
002  Dollar gains sales on Greenspan speech\n\nThe dollar...     {'sales':1, 'gains':1}
003  Yukos unit buyer faces loan claim\n\nThe owner...           {'loan':1}
004  High fuel prices hit BA's profits\n\nBritish A...               NaN
005  Pernod takeover talk lifts Domecq\n\nShares in...               NaN
```

What would my approach be for this? I tried using collections.Counter() but I haven't been able to implement what I want. Thanks a bunch :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can define a function to count the keywords, store them in a dict and return it.

First, I would recommend preprocessing the text (lower, tokenizing, removing stopwords, punctuation) to make it easier to process.

So first, you would need to define a function that will preprocess the text, and for that, I would recommend using the [nltk library](https://www.nltk.org/) (the stopwords part is optional but it doesn't hurt so much to do it :D):

```
import string
from nltk.corpus import stopwords

def preprocess_text(text):
    text = text.lower() # To lower
    text = text.replace('\n',' ') # Removing line breaks
    translator = str.maketrans('', '', string.punctuation)
    text = text.translate(translator) # Removing punctuation
    filtered_words = [w for w in text.split() if w not in stopwords.words('english')] # Removing stopwords from the tokenized text
    return ' '.join(filtered_words) # We return the resulting list as a string
```

After that, you can define your custom function that will count the keywords

```
KEYWORDS = ['sales','gains', 'loan', 'forex']

def count_keywords(text):
    counts = {}
    prep = preprocess_text(text)
    for kw in KEYWORDS:
        counts[kw] = prep.count(kw)
    return counts
```

And finally, apply that to your DataFrame

```
df['occurrences'] = df['text'].apply(count_keywords)
```

Comment: Thanks a bunch, dude.. :D

Answer (score 1):

We can use `str.extractall` over your keywords and create a custom dict to map back to your original df.

```
from collections import defaultdict

keywords = ['sales','gains', 'loan', 'forex']
s = (df.set_index('id')['text'].str.extractall(f"({'|'.join(keywords)})")
 .groupby(level=0)[0].value_counts().to_dict()

)

map_dict = defaultdict(list)
for k,v in s.items():
    map_dict[k[0]].append({k[1] : v})


print(map_dict)
#out:
defaultdict(list,
        {1: [{'sales': 1}],
         2: [{'sales': 2}, {'gains': 1}],
         3: [{'loan': 1}],
         4: [],
         5: []})


df['counter'] = df['id'].map(map_dict)
```

---

```
   id                                               text  \
0   1        Ad sales boost Time Warner profit Quarterly   
1   2  Dollar gains sales on Greenspan speech The dol...   
2   3        Yukos unit buyer faces loan claim The owner   
3   4        High fuel prices hit BA's profits British A   
4   5        Pernod takeover talk lifts Domecq Shares in   

                        counter  
0                [{'sales': 1}]  
1  [{'sales': 2}, {'gains': 1}]  
2                 [{'loan': 1}]  
3                            []  
4                            []
```

Comment: Thanks a bunch, dude..this works as well, but I was looking for an NLP based approach.

Comment: @DevarshiGoswami no problemo - put that in your requirements next time.